# WMIC error: desciption = exception occured when searching for hotfix

Tags: wmic

I have a wmic command I want to run that would query a list of machines and return a csv file if a hotfix is installed. In my case the hotfix ID is 2617858. It starts to process and then comes up with this after about 20 seconds: error: desciption = exception occured . It works when there are a few machines in the file but I need to run it against 40 computers.

Any suggestions ? Thanks

CODE:

```
 wmic /failfast:on /node:@"C:\users\username\desktop\servers.txt" qfe | find "2617858" > \\computername\C$\users\username\desktop\hotfix.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, it might be easier to ask `wmic` to filter rather than piping `wmic` through `find`.  Something like this:

```
wmic /node:@"C:\users\username\desktop\servers.txt" qfe where hotfixid="KB983590" get csname /format:list >>hotfix.txt
```

Or if the problem is that `wmic` can't handle that many servers in servers.txt, try looping through the list with a batch `for` loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("C:\users\username\desktop\servers.txt") do (
    set /P "=Checking %%I... "
    wmic /node:%%I qfe where hotfixid="KB983590" get csname /format:list >>hotfix.txt 2>>failures.txt
    echo Done.
)
echo Unable to query the following computers:
type failures.txt
```

As an alternative, you can perform the same action using PowerShell.

```
powershell -command "$pcs = Get-Content C:\users\username\desktop\servers.txt; foreach ($pc in $pcs) { Get-WmiObject -Computername $pc Win32_QuickFixEngineering | where-object {$_.hotfixid -eq 'KB980232'} | select-object csname }" >>hotfix.txt
```

... although if wmi is unresponsive on the server for wmic, you probably won't have much better luck using powershell.